# Mof file is missing when trying to connect Reporting Service Config Manager

Tags: reporting-services

Now the problem becomes the system cannot find specified path when trying to located mof file in command prompt. For my case, I need to use 110 because I am using SQL server 2012. When I check inside Window/System32/...I cannot find mof file. Anywhere I can download Mof file?